# Not able to get result of Nightmare from cron execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, fs, nightmare

I've been working on some automation process with Nightmare and cron. After Nightmare runs, it gets the value of the result and appends it to a file in my local computer (no network issues detected).

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var fs = require('fs');
var filePath = `${process.env['HOME']}/Documents/ResultCron.txt`;

Nightmare()
    .goto('http://mywebsite.com/form')
    .type('input[id="email"]', 'XXX@gmail.com')
    .click('#submit-button')
    .wait('.formSubmitted')
    .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.formSubmitted').value)
    .end()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`The form submitted is:\n${result}`)
      fs.appendFileSync(filePath, `\n${result}: ${new Date()}`);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
      fs.appendFileSync(filePath, `\nERROR: ${error}: ${new Date()}`);
    })
```

When I run this with `node /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.js` it's working perfectly and writting in the file. However, when executed from the cron it doesn't append anything to the file.

I've added the config to the crontab as following:

```
crontab -e

# It will be executed everyday at 13:00
0 13 * * * node /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.js
```

And if I do `grep nightmareForm.js /var/log/syslog -C 10` I can see it has been executed: 
`Apr 24 13:00:00 PC CRON[1223]: (root) CMD (node /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.js)`

Continuing the investigation, the file has this rights (Ubuntu 18.10): `-rwxr-xr-x` so it should be executable and the created file has the rights: `-rw-rw-rw-`

Update: After the ideas of @ponury-kostek I verified that the script can write in the file, but it never reaches the then() or catch() block

Update2: I tried to catch the logs from the crontab but it doesn't display any error: `0 13 * * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.js >> /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.log 2>&1`

Any ideas why from crontab the script is not able to reach the then() or catch() blocks?
Thank you

Comment: When you do `sudo crontab -e` you are editing `cron` for `root` (`process.env['HOME'] === "/root/"`) user not your. Just do `crontab -e` without `sudo`

Comment: @ponury-kostek Thanks for your answer, however, it's the same behaviour with sudo or without sudo. 
Log with the info (indeed we can see that root is not running in this one): `Apr 24 14:39:01 PC CRON[25564]: (user) CMD (node /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.js)`

Comment: Create file with `const fs = require("fs"); fs.appendFileSync("/tmp/crone_test.txt", JSON.stringify(process.env));` and run it from cron, then check whats set under `HOME`

Comment: You're completely right, the execution of the code can create and append details to the file. The problem then it's in the execution of Nightmare script. It never enters into the then() or catch() blocks...
I'll update the description of the issue, thanks again!

Comment: Wrap everything you can with `try/catch` block and log result somewhere, I think `nightmare` is not available for your script

Comment: I wrapped everything in a try-catch blocked but nothing is logged. Tried also with appendFile (async) just in case but same issue. I guess I'll switch for now to node-cron until someone posts a solution :)

Comment: Don't put root crontab commands in a user home. Use the user crontab instead: `crontab -e` without `sudo`.

Comment: Hello @ceving as you can see in the second comment it has the same behaviour with sudo or without sudo. I updated the description to avoid future confusions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same Problem.

what did the job for me was using  **xvfb-run** to start the node process.

```
xvfb-run node myscript.js
```

Actually i made shellscript (go.sh) that only contained 3 lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/me/nodestuff/spkfetch
xvfb-run node fetch_umsaetze.js
```

And added this to the crontab:

```
* * * * *  cd /home/norbert/nodestuff/spkfetch && sh go.sh  >> /home/norbert/nodestuff/spkfetch/log/log.txt  2>&1
```

I never tried to put the **xvfb-run**  call directly into the crontab, but i think its possibly an issue of the script not being allowed to start an X process(window) or something like that. Maybe its worth to try to put it directly into the cron command.

Here is the page that led me to this solution:
https://www.nickhart.co.uk/2019/08/09/scraping-with-nightmarejs-getting-started/#run_on_server

Comment: No need to add the go.sh file actually :) I managed to run xvfb-run directly on the crontab